# Javascript: Использовать массив в качестве последнего аргумента функции splice

Tags: javascript, функции

Синтаксис функции splice:

```
array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])
```

У меня есть массив из элементов *item1, item2, ...* . Как мне вставить его в эту функцию?

**ДОБАВЛЕНО:**
То есть как-то так: `array.splice(1, 1, ["a","b"])`

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ES2015 добавился [spread оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), он позволяет разворачивать массив в список аргументов

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.splice(1, 1, ...["a", "b"])
console.log(array);
```

Раньше пришлось бы использовать [метод apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3];
array.splice.apply(array, [1, 1].concat(["a", "b"])); // если все известно заранее можно сразу составить нужный массив [1,1,"a","b"]
console.log(array);
```